# MySQL Error : is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to execute this query but seeing an error in question 3 and 4.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ap;
CREATE DATABASE ap;
USE bohra001;

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 1) */
CREATE USER 'bohra001_1' IDENTIFIED BY 'bohra001_1';
CREATE USER 'bohra001_2' IDENTIFIED BY 'bohra001_2';
CREATE USER 'bohra001_3' IDENTIFIED BY 'bohra001_3';

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 2) */
GRANT CREATE, INDEX, DROP, ALTER ON bohra001.* TO 'bohra001_1'@'localhost';
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON bohra001.* FROM 'bohra001_1'@'localhost';

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 3) */
GRANT SELECT, CREATE VIEW ON bohra001.'PRESCRIPTION, PATIENT, DOCTOR' TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON bohra001.* FROM 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 4) */
GRANT ALL ON bohra001.* TO 'bohra001_3'@'localhost'
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 150
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 110
MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 55;

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 5) */
ALTER USER 'bohra001_1'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE;

/*  Assn 3, Task 1a, Qn 6) */
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'bohra001_1';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'bohra001_2';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'bohra001_3';

SELECT max_questions,
       max_updates,
       max_connections
FROM   mysql.user
WHERE  user = 'bohra001_1'
AND    host = '%';

SELECT bohra001_1 FROM bohra001;
```

The error in the following line says: "bohra001" is not valid at this position, identifier expected.
GRANT SELECT, CREATE VIEW ON bohra001.'PRESCRIPTION, PATIENT, DOCTOR' TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';

The error in the following line says: "WITH" is not valid at this position, identifier expected.
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 150

I am working on MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Does `bohra001.'PRESCRIPTION, PATIENT, DOCTOR'` must mean 3 separate tables? this is not correct, use 3 separate statements. *"WITH" is not valid at this position* WITH in GRANT cannot be used for variables assignement, see "GRANT Syntax". Use ALTER USER.

Comment: Thanks. The ALTER USER statement fixed the "WITH" issue. I tried to make 3 separate statements for the bohra001.'PRESCRIPTION, PATIENT, DOCTOR' problem but I am met with the same error in all 3 lines. Can you suggest any other solution ?

Comment: ```GRANT SELECT ON bohra001.PRESCRIPTION TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';``` ```GRANT SELECT ON bohra001.PATIENT TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';``` ```GRANT SELECT ON bohra001.DOCTOR TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';``` ```GRANT CREATE VIEW ON bohra001 TO 'bohra001_2'@'localhost';```